# MariaDB сортировка внутри группировки

Tags: mariadb

Один и тот же запрос выдает разные результаты.Есть несколько тестовых записей.

```
id number status

1 100 0
2 100 1
3 200 0
4 200 1
```

Пытаюсь сперва отсортировать,после этого сгруппировать по `number`. Вот результаты.`1 - вариант MariaDB 2 - MySql`. Почему поведение группировки разное?

```
1) 
id number status
1 100 0
3 200 0

2)
id number status
2 100 1
4 200 1


SELECT * FROM(
 SELECT * 
 FROM numbers
 ORDER BY id DESC
) as a
GROUP BY a.number
```

Comment: А где сам запрос?

Comment: Да небось `status` в выходном наборе - не в GROUP BY, не в групповой функции, а просто так. Вот и получается лотерея.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Не какие другие СУБД не позволяют использовать символ '*' в сочетании с `GROUP BY`, так как нельзя однозначно определить какое значение должно быть выведено для полей, которые не указаны в `GROUP BY` или агрегатных функциях.
В `MYSQL` и `MariaDB` для неоднозначных результатов запроса используется случайная запись, при этом `GROUP BY` исходит из того, как сделать свою работу быстрее, а не на том в каком порядке пришли на вход данные. Поэтому через некоторое время можно обнаружить, для той же базы данных и тех же данных результат изменился без видимых причин.
Вывод, не используйте в `SELECT` поля, которые не упомянуты в `GROUP BY` или вычислены через агрегатные функции (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` и т.д.)

Comment: Ссылка в догонку: http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html